# Silverstripe 3 Tables (1 Linking Table) ORM implementaton

Tags: orm, silverstripe

I got three database tables

Table Name  Columns
1           id1, column1
2           id2, column2 
3           id1, id2   (from tables 1 and 2)

So that if table 1 has column1 rows,

```
row 1 = a 
row 2 = b 
row 3 = c
```

and table 2has column2 rows

row 4 = d
row 5 = e

then if table 3 has rows

```
1 4   = a, d columns
1 5   = a, e columns
3 4   = c, d columns
1 5   = a, e columns
```

That means Table 3's pk1 and pk2 will get column1 and column2 from Tables 1 and 2 respectively.

Question is how do I implement this using Silverstripe's ORM?

Comment: A school includes two groups: Students and Classes. One student can attend many classes, and one class can contain many students. Hence, the "many-to-many" relationship between students and classes.  How do you relate the two groups using a Junction Table using Silverstripe's ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create the junction table for a many-to-many relationship in SilverStripe. That's really cool. You define the class relations using `$many_many` on one side and `$belongs_many_many` on the other side. And if you need some custom fields in the junction table (e.g. for custom sorting) you can define `$many_many_extraFields`

So a example could look like:

```
class Student extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(//your stuff here);
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Classes' => 'SchoolClass' // naming it "Class" won't work...
    );
    private static $many_many_extraFields = array(
        'SortOrder => 'Int'
    );
/* .... */
}

class SchoolClass extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(//your stuff here);
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Students' => 'Student' 
    );

/* .... */
}
```

See also:

- [Docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/relations/#many-many)
- [Lesson](http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-many-many)

Comment: Should the second class be "class SchoolClass extends DataObject" instead?